# Reset a single form to its initial state

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, vcl

I have multiple forms in one project: `frmBooking`, `frmWelcome`, `frmAdmin`.
I want to reset `frmBooking` (i.e., reset it to its initial state, as if it's just created with all the components) by clicking a button.
I tried doing the following:

```
frmBooking.Destroy;
Application.CreateForm(TForm, frmBooking);
frmBooking.Show;
```

The result, however, is that it just creates a blank form, not resetting the form to its initial state.

What can I do to reset the form?

Comment: You should use the actual form class instead of _TForm_.

Comment: Really not much point in using Application.CreateForm. Had you used the standard construction pattern then the compiler would have told you the mistake.

Comment: Note that it is not safe to destroy a Form object from inside one of its own event handlers (ie, a child button's `OnClick` event). So, you would have to delay such logic until after the event handler exits, such as by using `TThread.ForceQueue()`, `PostMessage()`, `TTimer`, etc. A better design would be to not destroy the Form at all, but simply expose a method to reset its internal state as needed (reset UI controls, set data members to default values, etc).

Comment: It's _its_, not _it's_.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, for destroying a form inside its own event handler a method called `Release` was invented: https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Alexandria/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Release

Comment: @UweRaabe yes, though `Release()` is *asynchronous*, as it posts a `CM_RELEASE` message to the Form's window, and then the message handler destroys the Form object. That means in the code presented above, the new Form would be created before the old Form is destroyed.

Comment: So what? As long as no global resources are used by the form instance, it should be possible to have multiple instances at the same time. One can just hide the old form before calling Release to avoid having both forms visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your initial approach I put together some code.

```
var
  theOwner: TComponent;
begin
  { make sure that we don't kill ourselves. 
    can be omitted if we are sure it cannot happen. }
  theOwner := Owner;
  while theOwner <> nil do begin
    if theOwner = frmBooking then
      raise Exception.Create('cannot recreate owner form');
    theOwner := theOwner.Owner;
  end;
  
  { find out who must be the owner of the newly created instance }
  theOwner := frmBooking.Owner;
  frmBooking.Free;
  frmBooking := TfrmBooking.Create(theOwner);
  frmBooking.Show;
end;
```